# Angular dynamic DI with string token

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-di

Seems that Angular 6 (4+?) requires token **objects** to be unique in order for the DI to work. Yet I want to use a dynamic token, to be provided from template html code, which will allow my new directive to resolve a service **by name**.

Currently the code:

```
this.service = this.injector.get(new InjectionToken<IServiceRef>(tokenName));
```

Fails with:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken the_token_name]:
```

When I replaced my code with the old depricated (in angular 4) Injector.get function, it works okay, because the injector compares names (and I do provide the service in the view by that name...). However with the new DI I am not able to achieve what I want.

So, how to tackle?

Comment: But these services are also hardcoded. So why not hardcode your tokens?

Comment: Constant hardcoded strings (which is what I have) are not enough. A single token OBJECT must be use in order for the DI mechanism to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a global storage object for your tokens. I recommend you use a map.

```
export const tokens: Map<string, InjectionToken<IServiceRef>> = new Map();
tokens.set('tokenName', new InjectionToken<IServiceRef>('tokenName'));
```

You have to use the map object to declare the provider.

```
@NgModule({
     providers: [
          {provide: tokens.get('tokenName'), useValue: new Service()}
     ]
 );
```

You can now look-up the token via the string value.

```
this.service = this.injector.get(tokens.get(the_token_name));
```

I did not know this had changed in Angular 6, but I do recall that the documentation says that tokens are by value reference. Which means that the DI uses `===` to match dependencies.

You will get collisions in the DI if you match by token names. Many libraries declare a "document" token as an example. So you don't want to be using string names. As a collision would be extremely difficult to find and fix.

Comment: Nice solution! I tried it before but I just missed the provide: part...

Comment: Awesome solution! Was able to implement a common interface use by multiple service implementation across various modules. @Reactgular, you save my life ;-)

Comment: Posted an answer who shows how I solve my problem with your solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67521314/6796524)